# How do I update the url in angular js with $route and $routeParams?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I redirect or update the url? I cannot find any good documentation regarding this. Basically, what I want to do is to change the $routeParams dynamically and update the url with the new value.

My code looks like this:

```
if ($routeParams.time) {
        var url;
        $routeParams.time = encodeURIComponent(value);
        url = '/' + $routeParams.time + '/' + 'marketing/networks';
        $location.path(url);
    } else {
        $routeParams.time = encodeURIComponent(value);
        url =  '/' + $routeParams.time + $location.path();
        $location.path(url);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636476/angularjs-best-way-to-update-route-parameter

Answer (score 23):

**After reading the comments to my answer, I think maybe is not the right answer for this case. Please, before using this solution, read the comments and other answers. I'm not using Angular anymore so I don't feel qualified for answering.**

**I leave the original answer unmodified below:**

You are changing the location properly but AngularJS it's not realizing that it changed.
You can solve the problem using the method '$apply' of your scope like this:

```
$location.path( url );
$scope.$apply();
```

Or like this:

```
$scope.$apply( $location.path( url ) );
```

See $apply documentation here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Comment: You may experience a $apply already in progress error, if so see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626039/apply-already-in-progress-error, it's easily fixable.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to call $apply unless you are interfacing from a non-Angular event. 

When using $apply consider using a "safe apply" approach:

https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma

This is NOT a case where you need to use apply!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try native browser object `$window.location.href` instead, according to [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) (in `Caveats` section).

Answer (score 2):

you should use https://angular-ui.github.io/

ui-router

when using this you can do ...

state.go("route-name", {id:4});

much better than the built in routing service

The most voted answer is worrying!