# AngularJS - Best way to update $route parameter

Tags: location, angularjs, routes

I have several routes that are different, but contain similar parameters.

**Example:**

```
when '/user/:accountId/charts/:chartType', controller:ChartsController
when '/manager/:accountId/charts/:chartType', controller:ChartsController
when '/whatever/pathy/paththingy/charts/:chartType', controller:ChartsController
```

Notice all three views use the same Charts Controller to control the view.  Its a fairly generic controller but it needs toggle between available chartTypes... while keeping the rest of the route.

**Example: (THIS DOESN'T WORK)**

```
if my currrent url is '/user/001/charts/comparison'
Then I call something like:
$route.current.params.chartType = 'newChart';
$route.reload(); // or soemthing similar?
I want the url to become '/user/001/charts/newChart'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to easily update parameters of a route without completely re-typeing or rebuilding the route path?

Answer (score 13):

Since angular 1.3 you can use `$route.updateParams(newParams)` to change route params.

[Here is a quote from the angular docs...](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route#updateParams)

> **$route.updateParams(newParams);**
>
> Causes `$route` service to update the current URL, replacing current route parameters with those specified
>   in `newParams`. Provided property names that match the route's path
>   segment definitions will be interpolated into the location's path,
>   while remaining properties will be treated as query params.

Answer (score 11):

If it's possible, I would recommend you to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead. It's more powerful than ngRoute in many aspects.

Essentially, this module has a higher level concept called **state** wrapping the underlying route which **shields you from working directly** with lower route level like route urls.

For a comparison: [What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)

With ui-router, you can implement your code like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('user.chart', {
     url: '/user/:accountId/charts/:chartType',   
     controller: "ChartsController"   
  })
 .state('manager.chart', {
     url: '/manager/:accountId/charts/:chartType', 
     controller: "ChartsController"
  })
 .state('pathy.chart', {
     url: '/whatever/pathy/paththingy/charts/:chartType', 
     controller: "ChartsController"
  })
```

And you could just use this code to navigate between states:

```
$state.go('user.chart',{chartType:'newChart'},{inherit:true});
```

[Documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Answer (score 5):

The lack of this simple feature annoyed me, so I [Implemented it and filed a PR on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8358)