# Where to Store Location Logic in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am learning what logic to put in Angular's various components, but am left unsure of the Angular-way to handle manipulation of the $location.

I have some code that I would like to convert to Angular. It takes the document.referrer and based on various factors, may scroll to an anchor in the page (/page#scrollTo).

Where would one put the logic for this in Angular? It does not seem suitable for a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your anchor scroll example, Angular provides an $anchorScroll service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll. In the docs example, $anchorScroll is used within a $controller. This would be a simple solution when using angular-route.js.

If instead using angular-ui-router.js, then scrollTo's would likely be handled by the $urlRouteProvider. This SO answer: [What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router) provides good info about the added functionality of ui-router.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite a lot to get your head around for beginners. I did not know of the anchor scroll service. Very useful.