# Redirection in AngularJS controller based on value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, controller

I'm really new to AngularJs and I can't find how to do the following :

A user is answering questions in a quiz.html page. 
Each answer is added to a "answers" list.
In a controller I want to redirect to a result.html page if my "answers" list contains 4 answers...

```
if (answers.length === 4) {
    ???? }
```

I know this is a simple question but I can't find any simple answer
Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)

Comment: What routing solution are you using?

Comment: Not really a duplicate though, but look into ngRoute.

Comment: I'm using the ionic framework so I guess i'm using ui-router ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Angular $location`

```
if (answers.length === 'whatever') {
    $location.path("/result")
}
```

In your app.js

```
$routeProvider.when('/result', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/result.html',
        controller: 'ResultCtrl'
    })...
```

> Make sure to inject the **$location** into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a ng-click when a user clicks, so in your controller you would have,

```
$scope.checkAnswerLength = function(){
    if (answers.length === 4) {
        $location.path("/result")
    }
}
```

Then in HTML add on click checkAnswerLength, and if the answers length is 4 it will redirect to route /result