# Hybrid app navigation menu design

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, multi-device-hybrid-apps

We want to create a hybrid mobile app, using HTML, Kendo-UI and AngularJS.

On the mobile app, we'll need to display left sidebar navigation menu with menu items to view the specific screens.

The confusion I'm facing is that should I use:

- Kendo-UI navigation control (using href=#), or the
- Angular router method

Comment: Please clarify? Could you rephrase this question a bit, I (think I) can sort of get the just of what you want.... but then again, I could be wrong?

Comment: @RohanBüchner - We need to build a hybrid mobile app with basic functionalities such as left side bar. As, I was researching got to know that we can use kendo ui mobile widgets for creating a navigation menu and route accordingly. Parallely, we are using angular js for data binding. Also, angular js supports routing mechanism. So, my question is whether we really need to go for kendo ui mobile? As we can achieve this requirement with html, css and angular itself. Hope, I'm clear now?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an open ended topic, and you'll need to asses the options, because both should work.

My thinking is, that Teleric built their own router to compensate for some of the default router's lack of whatever (features/flexibility/etc..). So to that extent, I'd suggest that you compare Kendo-UI-Routing vs Angular-UI-Routing vs ngRoute.

**Kendo-UI-Routing**

- I personally haven't used Kendo. But I have used Teleric components in the past, and for the most part I had a good dev experience, thus I'm assuming their router will be as good. Maybe have a look at their feature list on their site.

  [Kendo UI Forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/converting-angular-routing-to-kendo-ui-routing#Ml59Vjq050qeX_U_pzAWIQ)

  > The Kendo UI Routing and Views are somewhat similar to the Angular
  >   ones but feature several different concepts

**Angular-UI-Router vs ngRoute**

- I know that the Angular-UI-Router ([UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)) framework is generally better accepted in the community than the baked in angular router, and has been easier and more flexible to implement in my experience.

  [Comparison of UI-Router vs ngRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024270/1105314)

  > UI-router is a 3rd-party module and is very powerful. It supports
  >   everything the normal ngRoute can do as well as many extra functions.