# How to pass param in routeProvider in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use routeProvider in Angular JS:

```
.when('/profile/personal', {
       templateUrl: 'personal.html',
       controller: 'EditProfileController'
})
```

How I can pass param to controller `EditProfileController` and here call Ajax method that returns data. This data must be display in template of route in `personal.html`.

Example:

```
    .controller('EditProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
         // If was click on `/profile/personal` from route, must get patam `personal` and call method GetAjax(param);
         $scope.GetAjax = function (param){
            //here return data put it in template HTML from route
         }  

    }]);
```

My links are located in page by path:

`http://wd.tk/profile`

When I click to link route I get URL:

`http://wd.tk/profile#/profile/personal/1`

Id do:

```
.controller('EditProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
   console.log($routeParams);
}]);
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'idProfile' of undefined
```

Comment: where is this `param` coming from? Is it from the route Url?

Comment: If tell otherwise, when I click link from route, I must call AJAX in controller and responded data must be in template from route

Comment: You can specify a parameter in the route url with `"/profile/personal/:param"`, and the `param` is available via the injectable `$routeParams`, so, in the controller you can do `$routeParams.param`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, in your url configuration, you must put the parameter of url:

```
when('/profile/personal/:idProfile', {
       templateUrl: 'personal.html',
       controller: 'EditProfileController'
})
```

Now, in your EditProfileController, you should get the parameter and call to ajax request:

Inject the $routeParams object and get the parameter with

```
$routeParams.idProfile:

.controller('EditProfileController',  
function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

   var idProfile = $routeParams.idProfile;

   $http.get("service url").then(setData, setError);

   function setData(data) {
       $scope.data = data;
   }
   function setError() {
       alert("error on get data profile");
   }

}]);
```

In your html, you will show your data profile in the correct format.

But I recommend that all the ajax calls should groups in angular services.
PD:
Check It out angular ui router:

[What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)

hope this helps.

Comment: One moment please, what link must be for `/profile/personal/:idProfile` is `<a href="/profile/personal/1">Link</a>`?

Comment: So, but how to check if was click on `personal` and do request Ajax then. Now your code in controller is run always

Comment: Also I get error: TypeError: `Cannot read property 'idProfile' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You you need to change your $routeProvider, that should have `/profile/:type` instead of `/profile/personal` that means you are going to provide value for `:type` which can be accessible by injectin `$routeParams` service inside controller.

```
.when('/profile/:type', {
       templateUrl: 'personal.html',
       controller: 'EditProfileController'
})
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('EditProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
     $scope.profileType = $routeParams.type;
     $scope.GetAjax = function (){
        //here you have profile type in $scope.profileType
        //you can pass it to ajax by simply accessing scope variable.
        $http.get('/getprofiledata?type='+ $scope.profileType)
        .success(function(data){
           $scope.profileData = data;
        })
        .error(function(error){
           console.log('error occured')
        })
     }  
     $scope.GetAjax(); //calling it on controller init
}]);
```

**Update**

YOu had missed one of dependency `$routeParams` in array annotation.

```
.controller('EditProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
   console.log($routeParams);
}]);
```

Comment: How be if I need set `when` like as: `.when('/profile/contacts/', {
       templateUrl: 'personal.html',
       controller: 'EditProfileController'
})`

Comment: then you need to add one more when condition like `$routeProvider.when('/profile/:type', {
       templateUrl: 'personal.html',
       controller: 'EditProfileController'
}).when('/profile/contacts/', { templateUrl: 'personal.html', controller: 'EditProfileController' })`

Comment: Can you see please again my question and edit own answer? Because now are a lot moments

Comment: It works thabnks, can I check if exists `$routeParams.type = 1`?

Comment: @Hamed could you do upvote & accept my answer..Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76780/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-hamed).