# To ui-router or to not ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making a wizard which will help user in creating an item. It's a form with input boxes and dropdowns and a Next button. I'm not sure if it's proper to use ui-router to display next page when Next button is clicked. For now, I'm planning to use ui-router to display succeeding next pages.

How are you going to display the next page if you don't want to use ui-router?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ui-router or normal route provided by angular,ui-router comes with extra and powerful functionality like states and nested viees and all.
Go through this link for more info

[What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)

Comment: Yup, I'm very familiar with states and named views too. I was just thinking that ui-router might be too overkill. Back in the days, I remember writing a code(not sure if it was php or javascript), and the page was stored in a separate tab. It's already loaded in memory when I click the tab versus ui-router which we will call the state and the corresponding urltemplate.