# state provider and route provider in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Below is my app.js file

```
angular
  .module('repoApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/loginPage.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
angular
  .module('loginState',['ui.router']);
```

Below is my states file

```
angular
  .module('repoApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {

      $stateProvider.state('home1', {
        url:'/home1',
        templateUrl: 'views/modals/test.html'
      })
      .state('secondState',{
        url:'/secondState',
        templateUrl: 'views/modals/secondStateTest.html'
      });
  });
```

The problem is, using my html i navigate to login page.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="loginShift"><a ng-href="#/login">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
```

but I am trying to hit the state as soon my flow hit the controller

```
angular.module('repoApp')
  .controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope,$modal,$state) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $state.go('home1');
    $scope.openDialog = function () {
        $modal.open({
          keyboard: 'static',
          templateUrl: 'views/login/loginCred.html',
        });
      };        
  });
```

but I am not able to hit the home state.
If I change my states file i.e

```
$stateProvider.state('home1', {
            url:'/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/modals/test.html'
          })
```

here I changed URL. It works fine now.

I have a template from where I want to navigate to a next state

```
<div>
<button data-ng-click="openDialog()">open ME!</button>
<div><a ui-sref="secondState">click here</a></div>
</div
```

but as soon I click this anchor tag it navigates me back to home page. ie not to the state I intend to go.
The main issue is URL(i guess) any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please avoid any markup mistakes like missed symbols and all.  Need to know the functional issue.

Comment: I wouldn't use both `ngRoute` and `ui.router`; they're two different approaches to the same problem. I'd say the `$routeProvider.otherwise` rule is preventing your state configs from working

Answer (score 24):

You shouldn't use both `ngRoute` and `UI-router`. Here's a sample code for UI-router:

```js
repoApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html",
      controller: 'YourCtrl'
    })
    
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.html",
      controller: 'YourOtherCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
});
//etc.
```

You can find a great answer on the difference between these two in this thread: [What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router/#answer-21024270)

You can also consult UI-Router's docs here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router