# I need to get products when I clicked on the category list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Intelxdk for this application. This is a mobile application.

My categorylist will show, after that click on that, I have to redirect the product page, When I click on the category I can get some error like this. "Can't find variable: $state".

**CategoryController.js**

```
app.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope','getServices','JSONDataService', function($scope,getServices,JSONDataService) {

    var url = 'http://look4what.biz/mobile/shop-category.php';

    $scope.getId = function(termid){ 
        JSONDataService.addTansferData(termid);
        $state.go('/:id');
    }

    getServices.sendRequest(url)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.userslists = data;

         }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

         });

    }]);
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('LookApp', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngRoute','paymentCtrls']);  

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider 
            .when('/', {
                 controller: 'CategoryController',
                 templateUrl: 'views/category.html'
             })
             .when('/:id', {
                 controller: 'ProductController',
                 templateUrl: 'views/users.html'
             })
             .when('/login/:friendId', {
                  controller: 'LoginController',
                  templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
             })
             .otherwise({
                 redirectTo: '/'
             });
         });
```

**ProductController.js**

```
app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'category','JSONDataService','getServices', function($scope, $routeParams, category,JSONDataService,getServices) {

    $scope.newData = JSONDataService.getTansferData();

    term_id="+$scope.newData;

    var url = "http://look4what.biz/mobile/id-get-detail.php?term_id="+termid;

    getServices.sendRequest(url)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.userslists = data;

         })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

         });

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the *$state*-Service you need to inject it first:

```
app.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope','$state','getServices','JSONDataService', function($scope, $state, getServices, JSONDataService) {

    var url = 'http://look4what.biz/mobile/shop-category.php';

    $scope.getId = function(termid){ 
        JSONDataService.addTansferData(termid);
        $state.go('/', { id : termid});
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Now I have like this error. Could not resolve '/:id' from state ''

can you change app.js file for the $stateProvider

Comment: "/:id" is not valide state. Sorry i missed that. :id ist just a placeholder for different id's so you have to pass explicit some id. Updatet my answer

Answer (score 0):

here is the tiny example about inject $state as a service for your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $state) {
  $scope.changeState = function () {
    $state.go('contact.detail');
  };
});
```

and detailed explanation:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

[state provider and route provider in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370716/state-provider-and-route-provider-in-angularjs)

your code with $stateProvider:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
             url:'/'
             controller: 'CategoryController',
             templateUrl: 'views/category.html'
         })
         .state('id', {
              url:'/:id'
             controller: 'ProductController',
             templateUrl: 'views/users.html'
         })
         .state('login.friendId', {
              url:'/login/:friendId'
              controller: 'LoginController',
              templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
         })

     });
```

Comment: Now I have like this error. Could not resolve '/:id' from state '' 

can you change app.js file for the $stateProvider

Comment: I edited my explanation according to your code part. Maybe you want to see this tutorial for more information :
[link](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html)