# Unable to load css and other files when using ngRoute AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

```
   var voteApp = angular.module('VoteApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'students'
    ]);

voteApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'index.html',
        controller : 'MainController'
    });
});


voteApp.controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope){

 }]);
```

On loading, the whole page will crash!

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Check the console error log

Comment: provide the error message from console window

Comment: Was my answer of any help to you @Channox? If yes, then mark it or post your solution, so others who encounter the same problem like you did, will know how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you run your application on a server? If not go to your terminal and type in this: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and then open your application on localhost
2. Try using angular-ui-router instead of angular-route
   [What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)