# AngularJS fade view in/out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on creating a weather module for my SPA with **Angular 1.4** and attempting to fade my a view out as the other fades in, when the user clicks a button to retrieve the forecast for their city.

I have injected the `ngAnimate` module into my application, and attempted to write some CSS, as well as javascript. However, the animation doesn't work no matter what I try! Maybe I'm missing some fundamental concept of how animations work in angular?

---

**Here is my CSS:**

```
        .animate-enter, 
        .animate-leave { 
            -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
            -moz-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
            -ms-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
            -o-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
            transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: clip;
            white-space:nowrap;
        } 

        .animate-leave.animate-leave-active,
        .animate-enter {
            opacity: 0;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
        }

        .animate-enter.animate-enter-active, 
        .animate-leave {
            opacity: 1;
            width: 150px;
            height: 30px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

---

**Here is my main page, where my views are brought in:**

```
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS Weather</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#/" id="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container" ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}" ng-view></div>

</body>
```

---

**My app.js:**

```
    var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate']);

weatherApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .when('/forecast', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/forecast.html',
        controller: 'forecastController'
    })
    .when('/forecast/:days', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/forecast.html',
        controller: 'forecastController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
}])
```

---

**A view example:**

```
<div class="home row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h4>Forecast by City</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="city" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <a href="#/forecast" class="btn btn-primary">Get Forecast &raquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Lookup `$rootScope.$on($stateChangeStart, func...)` and `$rootScope.$on($stateChangeSuccess, func...)``$stateChange`. Should be place in the `.run` of your app.js

Comment: Also, instead of using ngRoute, you should go with ui-router

Comment: How would any of those solve his problem?

Comment: On the `$stateChangeStart` event you can grab HTML tags and set style attribute until the `$stateChangeSuccess` happens.

Comment: ui-router vs. ng-route -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/angularjs-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router

Comment: Thanks for the input @Shinobi881 , but I think that this suggestion takes a bit of a different direction than I am attempting to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up figuring it out. It was surprisingly much easier than I was making it!

1. The first thing that you have to do is to **inject `ngAnimate`** into your application like this:
   `var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate']);`
2. Create the CSS classes for your animation, just as you would for a non-angular/javascript website or application: 
   `.days {
   padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px;
   }
   .home, .forecast {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   }
   @keyframes fadeIn {
   0%    { opacity: 0; }
   50%   { opacity: .5; }
   100%  { opacity: 1; }
   }
   @keyframes fadeOut {
   0%    { opacity: 1; }
   50%   { opacity: .5; }
   100%  { opacity: 0; }
   }
   @keyframes slideOutLeft {
   to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
   }
   @keyframes slideInRight {
   from    { transform:translateX(100%); }
   to      { transform: translateX(0); }
   }
   .ng-enter           { animation: slideInRight 0.5s both linear, fadeIn 0.5s both linear; z-index: 8888;}
   .ng-leave           { animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s both linear, fadeOut 0.5s both linear; z-index: 9999;}`
3. Use your view normally and let ngAnimate handle the dirty-details! ngAnimate will automatically detect when views are in their `ng-enter` state or their `ng-leave` state. *This means that when these classes are applied to your entering/leaving views the animations will be picked up!* 
   `<div class="container-fluid"  ng-view></div>`