# AngularJS - Navigate to another view via $state.go

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic Framework to create a single page app for mobile. I have a tab based structure for the profile page. Inside the "Home" view, I have a link "Edit Profile" once clicked it should navigate to editprofile.html via ProfileManagementController.js. When I click it, nothing happens and no errors show in the console either. Only the url in the address bar gets updated.

Here is the route code in app.js:

```
.state('editProfile', {
    url: '/editProfile',
    views: {
      'tab-editprofile': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/profile/editprofile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileManagementController'
      }
    }
  })
```

Here it the ProfileManagementController.js snipper relevant to this feature:

```
$scope.goToEditProfile = function(path)
{
    $state.go(path);
}
```

This is the HTMl form for the Home tab view (tab-home.html) in which the button exist to navigate to edit profile :

```
<div>
          Name: {{tempUserObject.name}} <br/>
          Friends: {{tempUserObject.totalFriends}}<br/>
          Mobile: {{tempUserObject.mobile}}<br/>
          Username: {{tempUserObject.username}} <br/>  
          <br/>
            <button ng-click="goToEditProfile('editProfile')" class="button">Edit Profile</button>

        </div>
```

This is the URL originally when i first land on tab-home.html and after clicking the button that doesn't work:

> Before: http://127.0.0.1:49259/index.html#/tab/home
>   After: http://127.0.0.1:49259/index.html#/editProfile

Please help guide me to figure out what is going wrong with this link. I've used $state.go before in other places and it works well.

Update: editprofile.html added.

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="false" title="Edit Profile">
    <ion-content padding="'true'" class="has-header">
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 87px;"></div>
        <div class="button-bar"></div>
        <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Does changing it to a relative path work? i.e. `ng-click="goToEditProfile('^.editProfile')"`

Comment: @potatopeelings tried that already and it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

use this instead of state change.

```
 $location.path('/editProfile');
```

Dont forget to inject $location in your controller function.

Comment: Yup did that now and injected location but didn't work. Only URL changed to as mentioned earlier. $state is not the problem so $location is not the solution. Other functions in same app.js worked with state

Comment: do you use ui-router !! if yes then try `ui-sref ="editProfile"`

also go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/angularjs-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router

Comment: no I don't. Only using what comes with foundation AngularJS and Ionic Framework

Comment: It seems that ngRoute has hard dependency on Ionic framework, I don’t find anything wrong in your code, it may depend on versions of angular, or ionic framework too, might not work consistently in iterative versions. Matter of fact ngRoute is not a core package any more. esp., you using ionic they recommend ui-router. checkout  their blog.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/angularjs/controllers/view-state/

Comment: also go through this for resolving issue https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-state-go-to-navigate-between-views-doesnt-work-location-path-does/1846/13

Comment: Got it working.. made couple of changes so not sure which made it work. Will update as answer once I find the specifics

Comment: Great, do update the working code, so I can wrap my head around. :)

Comment: Ionic has ui-router default. Look http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView. Default router very uncomfortable!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a state named 'path' defined in your app.js?
If not create a state named 'path' with template and controller just like the 'editprofile' state

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the above issues with modifying the route in app.js to the following:

```
 .state('editprofile', {
    url: '/editprofile',
    templateUrl: 'templates/profile/editprofile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileManagementController'
  })
```