# Which is better ng-view or ui-view?

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

For big projects ui-router is preferred. But the main advantage it gives is nested view. But that can be achieved by ng-view also. So which one to choose?

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/21024270/6521116

Answer (score 19):

Use ui-router, because it is so much better than the native ng-view (nested views...). Also, AngularJS will be implementing a lot of the features that ui-router has into Angular 2.0.

[AngularJS 2.0 Router Design Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I3UC0RrgCh9CKrLxeE4sxwmNSBl3oSXQGt9g3KZnTJI)

***Why You Should Use UI-Router***

**Multiple Views**

Most applications can be broken up into regions. At a minimum, applications usually have a header, a main content area, and a footer.
In most use cases, all of these regions (views) are shown on the page at the same time. With the built-in AngularJS router, ngRoute, only one view (ng-view) is allowed per page. This limitation causes people to use includes (ng-include) or other workarounds to create a layout or master page for their application. UI-Router supports multiple views and each can have it’s own corresponding Controller so that each of these regions can be encapsulated and reused throughout the application if needed.

**Nested Views**

The common example of a nested view in applications is a master/detail or, more specifically, a list/detail page. Many applications show a list of items then when you click on an item you see the detail for that item. Taking this example further, you might then click an edit link when viewing the item’s details that takes you to an editable form for the item.

This scenario is easily achieved with the built-in AngularJS router, ngRoute, if the list and detail are on separate pages (or views as they are called in AngularJS). However, if you want the list to remain on the page while you show the detail to the right or below the list this becomes more challenging. To be clear, this requirement can be achieved with ngRoute by sharing a single view with two controllers: one for the list and one for the detail and hiding and showing the detail as needed. The result is not ideal because we would like the list and detail to each have their own controller and view with only one responsibility (showing a list or showing item details). By encapsulating these user interface areas in their own view we can have a more composable UI that allows us to bring the pieces together or break them apart as needed to meet requirements. Nested views enable us to not only bring these views together at the same time but also to nest a view inside another view

Comment: Thanks Russell.. Would up vote u if only had enough reputation