# Angular $routeprovider - filename as parameter

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have some old routes I would like to support in angular like that:

```
/2345.aspx
/4321.aspx
/123.aspx
```

Is there a way to map that with `$routeprovider`?

Something like:

```
 .when('/{path:.aspx}', {
    templateUrl : 'src/ng-app/views/posts/post.html',
        controller : 'postController'
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This code example use `ui-router`:

```
'use strict';

var states = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('main.post', {
      url: '/:postId' + '.aspx',
      templateUrl: 'src/ng-app/views/posts/post.html',
      controller: 'PostCtrl'
    });
};

states.$inject = [
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

That just works:

```
.when('/:path.aspx', {
     templateUrl : 'src/ng-app/views/posts/post.html',
     controller : 'postController'
})
```

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but the documentation says: *path can contain named groups starting with a colon: e.g. :name. All characters up to the next slash are matched and stored in $routeParams under the given name when the route matches.*. So if the documentation is correct, it shouldn't just work.

Answer (score 0):

It is always preferred to use ui-router over ng-router, which is more capable of handling states. Please refer the below link for more details on the difference between both.

[What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/angularjs-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)