# Is there a global resolver for $routeProvider in AngularJs 1.x?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to globally resolve a service for all the routes in AngularJs?

Let's say I need to get configuration from a Web Service for all the routes. Can we do something like the following pseudo-code?

```
$routeProvider
  .when('*', {
      resolve: {
         config: function(myConfigService) {
             return MyConfigService.getConfigPromise();
         }
      }
})
```

Comment: Not in ngRoute. Use angular-ui-router which allows nested routes and resolve of parent is passed to all descendents

Comment: @charlietfl can you write your comment as the answer with a sample code so I mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

ui-router might do the job instead. You can read up the difference between ui-router and ngRoute here:

[What is the difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/angularjs-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)