# Angular linking with routing and ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

I have routing set up to direct the user to various pages. Pretty standard stuff. On one of those pages however, I use ng-switch to show/hide 5 different sections. What I am looking to do, and I cant seem to find any info on it, Is I want to link to 1 of those 5 sections from a different page. Very similar to anchor tags in html.

So the question is, if i use routing from one page to another, how do i route to a specific section of that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't with `ngRouter`.

You can with `ui-Router`.

This SO question lists the main differences between `ngRouter` and `ui-Router` : [AngularJS : Difference between angular-route and angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/angularjs-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to different pages in your application, but you also want the application to be a SPA (Single Page Application), with no page reloading, you can use the ngRoute module.

The ngRoute module routes your application to different pages without reloading the entire application.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script
```