# Is templateUrl useful in ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router

Is it possible to use **templateUrl** instead of the embedded **template** in **ui-router**? If yes, which approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use templateUrl in ui-router.

```
.state('stateName', {
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
    controller: 'someController'
});
```

But which is the best approach is a trick question. Its all about how you are going to use the state. For example,

1. if your using angular 1.5 components, and need to call it as page, then it better to use `template`;

`.state('stateName', {
    template: '<component-name></component-name>'
});`

This is one of the most common approch for component. If you using ui-router version above 1.5, then you can do following too,

```
.state('stateName', {
     component: 'component-name'
 })
```

2. If you are using seperate template and controller it is better to use templateUrl,

`.state('stateName', {
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
    controller: 'someController'
})`

But directly writing the html like below is considered as bad practice

```
.state('stateName', {
    templateUrl: '<div><p>never do this</p></div>', 
    controller: 'someController'
});
```

Comment: You think which approach is better for reusability? I want to apply it for developing component based software product line. Can I create an Angular Component that uses templateUrl instead of template?

Comment: If you want to create reusable components, then defenitily you should stick with angular component, in that I would use template as mentioned in example 1 in the answer

Comment: And you suggest using ui-router better than ng-route?

Comment: Thats explained better here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/what-is-the-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router