# AngularJS 1, what logic decides where the output goes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How does angularjs decide where to output the content?

I have 3 levels of content, but ng-view only does one major one.

Think i'm going about it the wrong way, I have 3 sections (one left nav, second middle nav), then the third is the content section.

Basically I want to click the left navigation button, then it loads something within the section nav, then you click something within that middle nav and it loads content in the content section on the right.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction :).

Cheers,
Hayden

Comment: It is based on the <ui-view></ui-view> tag you are using with the routing and states. You have to share your code to figure out where is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that either using `routing` or by using `states`.
In the following example, I am using `states'

**[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:xyad7ztyMMOuKsK1TcKc?p=preview)**

So here when you click on 'Route1' that page will load and when you click on 'Show List' related list will show.

The main logic is in this code:

```
$stateProvider
.state('route1', {
  url: "/route1",
  templateUrl: "route1.html"
})
.state('route1.list', {
  url: "/list",
  templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
  }
})
.state('route2', {
  url: "/route2",
  templateUrl: "route2.html"
})
.state('route2.list', {
  url: "/list",
  templateUrl: "route2.list.html",
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
  }
})
```

So I have two states in my home page, one is 'route1' and other is 'route2' and these two states have specific content along with another nested state and it's specific view called as 'list', so I am using two `ui-view` to load the specific content in a container, one in 'index.html' and the other one is in 'route1.html' or 'route2.html'

This concept is called as **Nested States & Nested Views** and you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views).

Comment: Hey, this is pretty much what I'm after. Do you happen to have an example for using ngRoute instead of ui-router? 

From what I understand ngRoute is the newer version :)?

This is what my code is based off -> http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately `ngRoute` doesn't have the concept of nested views but there is one another module that can help you in that, read about it here: http://angular-route-segment.com/

Comment: Also one more thing, `ui-router` is latest not `ngRoute` and it's better, basically its ngRouter with more features, read the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/what-is-the-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router