# Transition from ng-view to ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-view

I have an older app (Angular 1.5.3) and I would like to take advantage of angular-ui-router and components for a few of my pages.

Is it possible to use the old routeProvider in conjunction with the stateProvider that ui-router provides?

IE I would like to transition a few pages to use components here and there as I get time, while leaving the rest.

I am pretty sure using ng-view and ui-view I am having a hard time getting that to work (probably cause you are not supposed to do that).  Does that mean I have to transition my entire project from routeProvider to stateProvider all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the old routeProvider in conjunction with the
>   stateProvider that ui-router provides?

#### Short answer

**No**. Similar structure but different syntax

#### Long answer

No, but ... You can easily convert `ng-view` to `ui-view` a.e. from `$routeProvider` to `$stateProvider`.

Consider example `ng-view`:

```
$routeProvider  
  .when('/Book/Add', {
    template: '<div class="box" ng-class="classname">Add</div>',
    controller: function($scope) {$scope.classname="add"}
  })
  .when('/Book/Error', {
    templateUrl : 'error.html',
    controller: 'ErrorController'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/Book/Error'});
```

Consider example `ui-view`:

```
 $stateProvider
 .state('book', {
                 url: '/Book',
                 abstract: true,
                 templateUrl: 'views/Book.html'
                })
.state('book.add', {
                    url: '/inbox',                    
                    template: '<div class="box" ng-class="classname">Add</div>',
                    controller: function($scope) {$scope.classname="add"}                     
                })
.state('book.error', {
                    url: '/Error',                    
                    templateUrl : 'error.html',
                    controller: 'ErrorController'                   
                })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
           return '/Book/Error';
          });
```

Keep in mind that routing syntax will change too.

For example:

```
 if ($state.current.name === 'login') {
      $state.go('book.add', {});
 }
```

Instead `<a href="/Book/Add">Add</a>` we will write `<a ui-sref="book.add">Add</a>`

And so on ......

---

As you can see, the syntax is a bit similar. I'm sure you will find a lot of references  about power of `$stateProvider`. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024270/1631379

Hope I answered on your question

Comment: answers it, and a great example of how to easily transition. Above and beyond, thanks so much.