# angular-route vs angular-ui-router who to work with?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know the question was answered before: [AngularJS Routing using ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023763/what-is-the-difference-between-angular-route-and-angular-ui-router)

But in 2018 (AngularJS 1.6.8) , does this answer still right? angular ui router is better angular route? angular route still won't allows nested views and multiple views?

Thanks,

Comment: `angular.run` might need a different state change listener. Instead of `$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",...` it should be `$transitions.onStart(...`. There might be some difficulties with nested views and CSS for them (_ng-animate?_). Overall it's better in every way

Comment: Which better? Angular ui router?

Comment: yup, it has more features and easier to work with