# How to perform click on Angular Material md-tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a `md-tabs` tag which 2 `md-tab` tags:

```
        <md-tabs id="tabs" class="md-accent" md-align-tabs="top" md-dynamic-height>
            <md-tab id="tab1">
                <md-tab-label>Tab 1</md-tab-label>
                <md-tab-body>
                    <div ng-include="'tab1.html'"></div>
                </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab id="tab2">
                <md-tab-label>Tab 2</md-tab-label>
                    <md-tab-body>
                        <div ng-include="'tab2.html'"></div>
                    </md-tab-body>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
```

I can switch between them properly by clicking in them (in the menu) but what I want is to be able to perform click on `tab1` for example. Let's say that inside on `tab2` I make a submit via `AJAX` and once I get the `success` I want to switch automatically to `tab1`.

I've tried lot of things, I've set the attribute `selectedIndex` from `md-tabs`, I've set the attribute `md-active` of `md-tab` to `true`. I've also tried to call the method which supposedly is fired by event click (`select()` from `$mdTabsCtrl`). But obviously nothing of this has worked.

So, how can I switch to a specific tab when I click one of my custom buttoms?

Comment: Is [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrMxWo) what you mean? Click on button map inside tab 1 and automatically you'll switch to tab 2.

Comment: Yup, that's it, but it doesn't work in my code, still dunno why.

Comment: Maybe you can try to make a plunker to reproduce the problem, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly change the value of selectedIndex in success block (selectedIndex value for the tab you wanna go).

In case you want to go to a specific tab then in a method put the selectedIndex value of the tab you wanna go..
to go on tab1 here is the method

```
$scope.firstTab = function() {
   $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
};
```

Calling this method after getting ajax call successful will always take you to first tab.
And for moving to next tab after every click here is the method

```
$scope.max = (number of tabs) - 1;
$scope.nextTab = function() {
   var index = ($scope.selectedIndex == $scope.max) ? 0 : $scope.selectedIndex + 1;
   $scope.selectedIndex = index;
};
```

Comment: Rakeschand, what's `vm`?

Comment: Btw, I don't really have 2 tabs, it was just an example, in fact I have 6 tabs.

Comment: no problem for six tabs max will  be 5 and I guess you are using $scope approach so don't worry about vm.. consider it as $scope.max

Comment: At the moment it doesn't... but it should, I'm messing with my code trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: why don't you create a plnkr and reproduce your problem?

Comment: I got it, it was just a misspelling in my code :( your solution is good, but you missunderstood what I wanted to do. It wasn't to go to the next tab, but just to go to the first tab (a specific tab). Correct your answer just in case another one comes here with the same problem and I'll mark it as accepted ;) thanks!!

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't accept your answer until it isn't clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111706/discussion-between-rakeschand-and-drumnbass).

Answer (score 2):

this works every time: `angular.element("md-tab md-tab-item")[0].click()`

Note: you may have to wrap this in a $timeout (i.e. setTimeout) if you are calling it from a function inside an angular controller [to avoid apply error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626039/apply-already-in-progress-error)