# Angular - run `$digest` without having `$scope`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller without `$scope`

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
    .controller('TodoListController', function() {
        var todoList = this;

        todoList.title = "Default title";

        setTimeout(function() {
            todoList.title = "Another title will appear after 5 seconds";
        }, 5000);

        // ...some magic here
    });
```

And view:

```
<h1>Current title: {{TodoListController.title}}</h1>
```

This code won't works correctly, becaufe function in `setTimeout` won't run `$digest()` which can update my `TodoListController.title`.

I know I can use `$scope` and use `$scope.$digest()`. But - is it possible to run `$digest()` without it? I have always access to object `angular`. Maybe through this object?

Comment: not specifically an answer, since the other answers are correct, but just because you use ControllerAs does not mean you are "without `$scope`"...  ControllerAs *abstracts* `$scope` by making the controller an aliased object on `$scope`, reducing (but not completely eliminating) your possible needs to interact with `$scope` directly.  You should not look at injecting `$scope` *when appropriate* as a bad design.

Comment: The question results from '$scope is bad' belief, which is false. $scope persecution is the most ridiculous thing that could happen with Angular community. Btw, $scope.$apply can be replaced with $rootScope.$apply and $rootScope.$digest. And btw, there are good reasons why this shouldn't be done and there's no good reason why this should.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$timeout` instead of vanilla setTimeout.

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
.controller('TodoListController', function($timeout) {
    var todoList = this;

    todoList.title = "Default title";

    $timeout(function() {
        todoList.title = "Another title will appear after 5 seconds";
    }, 5000);

    // ...some magic here
});
```

Using `$timeout` from angular will handle starting digest cycle.

Angulars $timeout is also useful if you want to notify angular to do updates without delay. In this case you can invoke it without second parameter.

```
$timeout(function(){
    //something outside angular ...
});
```

Function passed to `$timeout` will be invoked on next digest cycle.
This way is better than calling $digest manually because it will prevent [`digest already in progress`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626039/apply-already-in-progress-error) errors.

Comment: Oh... Timeout was only an example. It can be something different which don't fire angular `$digest()`.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the angular version of timeout: $timeout.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

This service trigger the angular $digest process.