# How to trigger an angular change from a non-angular context e.g. from a D3 event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.x and build a table using `ng-repeat` as shown below. However, now I need to show a new column depending on some dynamic boolean condition i.e. `isDynamicVisible`:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="name">Name</th>
        <th id="mean">Mean</th>
        <th ng-if="isDynamicVisible">Dynamic</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in displayedPathStatistics" ng-class="{selected: (histogramData.selected === data.name)}"
        ng-click="selectPathOutputRow(data.name)">
        <td>{{data.displayName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.Mean}}</td>
        <td ng-if="isDynamicVisible">{{dynamicVal}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On the controller side:

```
constructor(private $window: IWindowService, private $rootScope: IRootScopeService, private $scope:IReportCtrlScope, private $location:ng.ILocationService, private remoteServices: RemoteServices) {
    $scope.isDynamicVisible = false;

    // ...
    objects.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .classed("dot", true)
    .attr("r", function (d) {
            return 6 * Math.sqrt(2.0 / Math.PI);
    })
    .attr("transform", transform)
    .style("fill", colorVal)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        $scope.isDynamicVisible = true;
        return tip.show(d);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        $scope.isDynamicVisible = false;
        return tip.hide(d);
    });
```

The problem is that the condition is evaluated only once at the beginning and upon constructing the table, later no matter that the `isDynamicVisible` scope variable changes it will stay how it initially was. I have also tried using `ng-show` without success.

**UPDATE:** the `isDynamicVisible` is changed from the Controller specifically when the user hovers over a data point of a D3 JS scatter plot.

Comment: is `isDynamicVisible` a boolean or a function?

Comment: can you add the thing just before the `.on()`?

Comment: Is kind of irrelevant but Ok. I have already tested that the code there executes correctly etc.

Comment: Avoid `jquery`, and use `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseout` directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your listeners are fired from a non-angular context (i.e. from D3), you have to wrap your `$scope` attributes modifications under a [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) call:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.isDynamicVisible = true;
    }
    return tip.show(d);
})
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.isDynamicVisible = false;
    }
    return tip.hide(d);
})
```

Hence, the Angular digest cycle will be started and your view will update itself.

Comment: That's it, you nailed it Sir :)

Comment: you should pay attention to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626039/apply-already-in-progress-error

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: that's correct! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You issue is caused by the way change detection works in angularjs. When you bind your code to something else than an angular event, angular is not aware that you updated some properties, and does not trigger his `$digest` cycle, which updates views

you need to use the directive `ngMouseOver` inside your template :

```
<div ng-mouseover="isDynamicVisible = true" ng-mouseout="isDynamicVisible = false">
   some html element
</div>
```

If, this div is out of your controller (which should not happen) you should use

```
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.isDynamicVisible = false;
    }
    return tip.hide(d);
});
```

Comment: then, you should use $timeout() instead of $scope.$apply() to avoid concurrent $apply inside your application.

Comment: by the way, I think you should have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `$timeout`. It'll guarantee, that you'll have at least one another digest loop, so you'll not be forsed to use `$apply`. From the user point of view, there will be no difference.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.isDynamicVisible = true;
      return tip.show(d);
    })
})
```