# find the cause of Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

My application has a dashboard with some panels, each one with a chart.(I use [Angular-Chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)) Each panel is a different custom directive.

I have TickService with a global *tick*, broadcasted each 1sec

```
 function sendUpdateTich()
    {      
     $rootScope.$broadcast("TICK_UPDATE_TIME");
     $timeout(sendUpdateTich, 1000);
    }
```

Each directive listens for the *tick*, to update their own graphics.

```
    $scope.$on("TICK_UPDATE_TIME", function (event, data) 
                            {
                             /* update chart's data */
                             //  $scope.$apply();
                            });
```

Even if, by my own logic, I would use `$scope.$apply()` to refresh the directives' charts, I commented it out since it's useless, charts are already refreshed by them selves.

Anyway sometimes I've got this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13443:32
beginPhase@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30758:31
$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30498:21
http://localhost:8100/js/orecchioDirective.js:25:40
$broadcast@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30723:33
stopCheckinProximity@http://localhost:8100/js/callTimeService.js:226:26
stopChecking@http://localhost:8100/js/callTimeService.js:163:25
setEnded@http://localhost:8100/js/statusCallService.js:62:34
endCall@http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:319:31
fn
http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65429:21
$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30500:30
http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65428:19
defaultHandlerWrapper@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16792:15
eventHandler@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16780:23
dispatchEvent@[native code]
triggerMouseEvent@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2953:20
tapClick@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2942:20
tapMouseUp@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:3018:13
```

It doesn't occur at every tick, but just sometimes, I think (I don't know, but I just think..) according to some other $broadcasted event. I don't have any $scope.$apply, $rootScope.$apply neither $scope.$refresh, anywhere in the code. What's the problem?

[UPDATE 1]
According to [this](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout), `$timeout()` does the `$apply()` call for us so we don't have to. Since I have others `$timeout()` in Services, is it possible that they messy together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$apply already in progress error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626039/apply-already-in-progress-error)

Comment: Try using `$interval` every 1 second instead of a `$timeout` that recursively calls that function. There may be some issues with how you call `$timeout`.

Comment: @RameshRajendran  I don't think it's a duplicated question because I don't use any $scope.$apply, as the other user of that question does. Maybe it's a different problem.

Comment: are you sure you need an excplicit call to apply()? post the code inside the apply

Comment: no, I don't use $apply() anywhere in the code. I just use $scope and $rootScope to $broadcast and listen $on my custom events

Comment: @DeLac Instead of making people guess, create a minimal working example with the issue and you will start getting solid answers!